# Add peers in existing hyperledger fabric test-network

Tags: windows, docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode, peer

I am trying to insert new peers in existing hyperledger fabric test-network(v2.4).
The network is running in windows using docker. I need to add another system as the new peer.
Kindly provide the steps to do it.Also, how to provide tls certificates.

Firstly, I tried to add the new peer in my own system where network is running.
I tried to generate certificates using cryptogen command. The peer was added and it joined the channel but could not deploy chaincode in it.